# Node Inspector not showing my Node application

Tags: node.js, node-inspector

I've followed all the steps for using Node-Inspector

[image]
[image]

But when I open up the application, I can't see any of my scripts or logs to the console.

[image]

My app is running on port 4000. The only thing I thought that might be conflicting is WAMP on port 8080 as well, but changing Node-Inspector's port to 1000 didn't help.

Any thoughts about why this might be happening?

Comment: I had this veey sane problem today. For me,  a node process was hung. `taskkill node.exe` fixed my problem.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be it. :\ I do have Redis and Mongo open. Could either of those conflict?

Comment: Do you have any browser add-ons installed? Try to disable your anti-virus, some AVs tamper Node Inspector's connectons.

Comment: That's a good thought. I'm using the default Windows Defender on Windows 8 and AdBlock, but I checked and neither of those appear to be the issue.

Comment: All times AdBlock is a problem for node-inspector. Are you sure that disabling adblock not helful for you?

Comment: Disabling AdBlock on localhost did not make a difference.

Comment: @J4G have you restarted by chance? I just want to rule out the potential of any hung node processes.

Comment: @J4G, please open Dev Tools console (```ctrl+shift+J```) on Node Inspector page. Have you any error messages here?

Comment: No errors, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

The debugger will only work if open in one browser window. Make sure you don't have the debug url open in any other tabs / windows.